# Calculate sum of a column by ID based on the value of another column in R

Tags: r

I have some data that looks like this:

```
E_Add  Action  ActionType  Call  Callback  Email
xxxx   Task    Call        1     0         0
xxxx   Task    Call        1     0         0
xxxx   Event   Start       0     0         0
xxxx   Task    Call        1     0         0
xxxx   Event   Trial       0     0         0
yyyy   Task    Call        1     0         0
yyyy   Task    Callback    0     1         0
yyyy   Task    Email       0     0         1
yyyy   Task    Call        1     0         0
yyyy   Event   Start       0     0         0
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
E_Add  Action  ActionType  Call  Callback  Email CallSum CallbackSum EmailSum
xxxx   Task    Call        1     0         0
xxxx   Task    Call        1     0         0     2
xxxx   Event   Start       0     0         0     
xxxx   Task    Call        1     0         0     1
xxxx   Event   Trial       0     0         0
yyyy   Task    Call        1     0         0            
yyyy   Task    Callback    0     1         0             1
yyyy   Task    Email       0     0         1                         1
yyyy   Task    Call        1     0         0     2
yyyy   Event   Start       0     0         0
```

I mean it could look different than that, but that's the idea of what I want. I want to sum "calls", "callbacks", and "emails" by email and put them in a new column. But I want to reset the sum of "calls", "callbacks", or "emails" everytime I hit an "Event" in the Action column and of course do this by email.

Comment: Your description is unclear. Why in callSum column, for first email, the sum is written on the event line the first time and not on the event line the second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired output isn't very clear, but I think this does what you need (you also have `Email` column twice)

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("Call", "Callback", "Email") # Choose columns to modify
```

**First solution** (simple version)

```
setDT(df)[, paste0(cols, "Sum") := 
            lapply(.SD, function(x) c(rep(0L, .N - 1L), sum(x))),
            by = .(E_Add, cumsum(Action == "Event")), 
            .SDcols = cols][]

#     E_Add   Action ActionType Call Callback Email.1 CallSum CallbackSum EmailSum
#  1:  xxxx   Task       Call    1        0       0       0           0          0
#  2:  xxxx   Task       Call    1        0       0       2           0          0
#  3:  xxxx  Event      Start    0        0       0       0           0          0
#  4:  xxxx   Task       Call    1        0       0       1           0          0
#  5:  xxxx  Event      Trial    0        0       0       0           0          0
#  6:  yyyy   Task       Call    1        0       0       0           0          0
#  7:  yyyy   Task   Callback    0        1       0       0           0          0
#  8:  yyyy   Task      Email    0        0       1       0           0          0
#  9:  yyyy   Task       Call    1        0       0       2           1          1
# 10:  yyyy  Event      Start    0        0       0       0           0          0
```

---

**Second solution** To match your *exact* output

```
setDT(df)[, paste0(cols, "Sum") := 
            lapply(.SD, function(x) {
            if(any(x == 1L)){
              indx <- max(which(x == 1L))
              x[indx] <- sum(x) 
              x[-indx] <- 0L
              x
              } else 0L
           }), 
            by = .(E_Add, cumsum(Action == "Event")), 
           .SDcols = cols][]

#     E_Add   Action ActionType Call Callback Email.1 CallSum CallbackSum EmailSum
#  1:  xxxx   Task       Call    1        0       0       0           0          0
#  2:  xxxx   Task       Call    1        0       0       2           0          0
#  3:  xxxx  Event      Start    0        0       0       0           0          0
#  4:  xxxx   Task       Call    1        0       0       1           0          0
#  5:  xxxx  Event      Trial    0        0       0       0           0          0
#  6:  yyyy   Task       Call    1        0       0       0           0          0
#  7:  yyyy   Task   Callback    0        1       0       0           1          0
#  8:  yyyy   Task      Email    0        0       1       0           0          1
#  9:  yyyy   Task       Call    1        0       0       2           0          0
# 10:  yyyy  Event      Start    0        0       0       0           0          0
```

---

Edit per comment (If you want to display sum on `Event`

```
df[, paste0(cols, "Sum") := 
     lapply(.SD, function(x) c(rep(0L, .N - 1L), sum(x))),
     by = .(E_Add, cumsum(c(FALSE, (Action == "Event")[-length(Action)]))), 
          .SDcols = cols][]

#     E_Add Action ActionType Call Callback Email CallSum CallbackSum EmailSum
#  1:  xxxx   Task       Call    1        0     0       0           0        0
#  2:  xxxx   Task       Call    1        0     0       0           0        0
#  3:  xxxx  Event      Start    0        0     0       2           0        0
#  4:  xxxx   Task       Call    1        0     0       0           0        0
#  5:  xxxx  Event      Trial    0        0     0       1           0        0
#  6:  yyyy   Task       Call    1        0     0       0           0        0
#  7:  yyyy   Task   Callback    0        1     0       0           0        0
#  8:  yyyy   Task      Email    0        0     1       0           0        0
#  9:  yyyy   Task       Call    1        0     0       0           0        0
# 10:  yyyy  Event      Start    0        0     0       2           1        1
```

Comment: I think this should work as I suspect the CallSum on the 3rd row as a typo.

Comment: @akrun yes, I also think it was a typo, thus , this seem to match *exact* output.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked perfectly despite my poor explanation of the problem.

Comment: What if I wanted to output the sums to the line where"Event" is?

Answer (score 1):

```
df = structure(list(Email = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("xxxx", "yyyy"), class = "factor"), Action = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Event", "Task"
), class = "factor"), ActionType = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Call", "Callback", "Email", 
"Start", "Trial"), class = "factor"), Call = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Callback = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Emails = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L)), .Names = c("Email", "Action", "ActionType", "Call", "Callback", 
"Emails"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df$CallSum=''
df$CallBackSum=''
df$EmailSum=''

CSum =0
CBSum =0
ESum =0
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

CSum = CSum+ df[[4]][i]
CBSum = CBSum+ df[[5]][i]
ESum = ESum+ df[[6]][i]

if(df[[2]][i] == 'Event'){

#
df[[7]][i] = CSum
df[[8]][i] = CBSum
df[[9]][i] = ESum

#clear out vars
CSum =0
CBSum =0
ESum =0
}

}



   Email Action ActionType Call Callback Emails CallSum CallBackSum EmailSum
1   xxxx   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
2   xxxx   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
3   xxxx  Event      Start    0        0      0       2           0        0
4   xxxx   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
5   xxxx  Event      Trial    0        0      0       1           0        0
6   yyyy   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
7   yyyy   Task   Callback    0        1      0                             
8   yyyy   Task      Email    0        0      1                             
9   yyyy   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
10  yyyy  Event      Start    0        0      0       2           1        1
```

Comment: How does your loop know to execute this "by Email"?

Comment: How could you put this into a function and then apply it to the data by "email"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt. I eventually overwrote the three columns (i.e., Call, Callback, and Email.1). This could be one way to get what you are after. Initially, I created a group variable in the first `mutate`. I grouped the data by Email and group, and calculated sum for Call, Callback, and Email.1. Finally, I wanted to have zeros rather than empty space. So I used `replace()` in the final `mutate`.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

group_by(mydf, Email) %>%
mutate(group = ifelse(Action == "Event", row_number(), NA),
       group = na.locf(group, fromLast = TRUE)) %>%
group_by(Email, group) %>%
mutate_each(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)), Call:Email.1) %>%
mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(Action != "Event"), 0)), Call:Email.1) %>%
ungroup %>%
select(-group)

#   Email Action ActionType Call Callback Email.1
#1   xxxx   Task       Call    0        0       0
#2   xxxx   Task       Call    0        0       0
#3   xxxx  Event      Start    2        0       0
#4   xxxx   Task       Call    0        0       0
#5   xxxx  Event      Trial    1        0       0
#6   yyyy   Task       Call    0        0       0
#7   yyyy   Task   Callback    0        0       0
#8   yyyy   Task      Email    0        0       0
#9   yyyy   Task       Call    0        0       0
#10  yyyy  Event      Start    2        1       1
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(Email = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("xxxx", "yyyy"), class = "factor"), Action = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Event", "Task"
), class = "factor"), ActionType = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Call", "Callback", "Email", 
"Start", "Trial"), class = "factor"), Call = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Callback = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Email.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Email", "Action", "ActionType", "Call", 
"Callback", "Email.1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```