# Calculate sum of a column for rows that precede a specific value in another column by ID in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

So this is a continuation of a question I had asked a few days ago. The original data looks like this:

```
E_Add  Action  ActionType  Call  Callback  Email
xxxx   Task    Call        1     0         0
xxxx   Task    Call        1     0         0
xxxx   Event   Start       0     0         0
xxxx   Task    Call        1     0         0
xxxx   Event   Trial       0     0         0
yyyy   Task    Call        1     0         0
yyyy   Task    Callback    0     1         0
yyyy   Task    Email       0     0         1
yyyy   Task    Call        1     0         0
yyyy   Event   Start       0     0         0
```

This is how I want the data to look:

```
   Email Action ActionType Call Callback Emails CallSum CallBackSum EmailSum
1   xxxx   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
2   xxxx   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
3   xxxx  Event      Start    0        0      0       2           0        0
4   xxxx   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
5   xxxx  Event      Trial    0        0      0       1           0        0
6   yyyy   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
7   yyyy   Task   Callback    0        1      0                             
8   yyyy   Task      Email    0        0      1                             
9   yyyy   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
10  yyyy  Event      Start    0        0      0       2           1        1
```

This is some code to generate the original dataset. **It is not my own code; I did NOT write it.**

```
df = structure(list(Email = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("xxxx", "yyyy"), class = "factor"), Action =     
structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Event", "Task"
), class = "factor"), ActionType = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Call", "Callback", "Email", 
"Start", "Trial"), class = "factor"), Call = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Callback = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Emails = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L)), .Names = c("Email", "Action", "ActionType", "Call", "Callback", 
"Emails"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df$CallSum=''
df$CallBackSum=''
df$EmailSum=''

CSum =0
CBSum =0
ESum =0
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

CSum = CSum+ df[[4]][i]
CBSum = CBSum+ df[[5]][i]
ESum = ESum+ df[[6]][i]

if(df[[2]][i] == 'Event'){

#
df[[7]][i] = CSum
df[[8]][i] = CBSum
df[[9]][i] = ESum

#clear out vars
CSum =0
CBSum =0
ESum =0
}

}



   Email Action ActionType Call Callback Emails CallSum CallBackSum EmailSum
1   xxxx   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
2   xxxx   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
3   xxxx  Event      Start    0        0      0       2           0        0
4   xxxx   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
5   xxxx  Event      Trial    0        0      0       1           0        0
6   yyyy   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
7   yyyy   Task   Callback    0        1      0                             
8   yyyy   Task      Email    0        0      1                             
9   yyyy   Task       Call    1        0      0                             
10  yyyy  Event      Start    0        0      0       2           1        1
```

Basically the code does what I want it to do, but in my larger dataset, it doesn't work properly. I need to know of a way to wrap this code into a function and apply to chunks of the same email address (like apply by email address). As it is right now, the code will sum calls, emails, and callbacks, and then reset the "summation" everytime it reaches an event. I need it to reset everytime a new email address is reached. I want it to loop through the email addresses, hit an event, then count the calls, callbacks, and emails preceding the event and put those sums in new columns.

There can also be a scenario where an event occurs and there is some activity after that and then another event. So I would need to count the activity before the second event since there are no calls, emails, or callbacks preceding the first event for that email address.

I have tried this:

```
e_all_copy$CallSum=''
e_all_copy$CallBackSum=''
e_all_copy$EmailSum=''


get.total <- function(x) { for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {

  CSum =0
  CBSum =0
  ESum =0

  CSum = CSum+ x[[4]][i]
  CBSum = CBSum+ x[[5]][i]
  ESum = ESum+ x[[6]][i]

  if(x[[2]][i] == 'Event'){

    #
    x[[7]][i] = CSum
    x[[8]][i] = CBSum
    x[[9]][i] = ESum

    #clear out vars
    CSum =0
    CBSum =0
    ESum =0
  }
  CSum
  CBSum
  ESum
}}


e_all_summed <- ddply(e_all_copy,.(email),get.total)
```

But the output is just a list of all unique email address with NULL next to them. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Linking to the question you asked before might help to understand the context.

Comment: I provided you the solution in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146883/calculate-sum-of-a-column-by-id-based-on-the-value-of-another-column-in-r/29147589#29147589). What's wrong with it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146883/calculate-sum-of-a-column-by-id-based-on-the-value-of-another-column-in-r

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm curious about the for loop solution that was provided as well.